# Avoid saving entity in EBean

Tags: playframework, ebean

i want to use an ebean entity only as a usual object to store local data without saving or loading data from the database. Is it possible to prohibit saving an entity object? In other words: i create an new entity object and i want to prohibit the save function of this specific entity object. I need it to be save that there is no temporary and unwanted data send to the database.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Rob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you could Override the `save()` and `update()` functions from Model.java, and just have them either throw Runtime Exceptions or just do nothing at all.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a simple Java class that instantiate and store objects in memory? Objects will be garbage collected after your temporary usage.
Just remove your Ebean annotations and you are set.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am using the entities to get data and save data to the database. But there is one case where i only want to use the entity as a pure java class. Of course I can design a new java class which is like the entity. The problem is that I will have to maintain more than the entity class if I do so. I wanted to avoid that effort.

Thanks, Rob